# Some pins don't work with pigpio

Tags: pi-4, pigpio

Some pins (eg, GPIO 17, GPIO 26) don't work when using pigpio. I launch pigpio deamon using
`sudo pigpio -x -1` to enable all pins, but the two mentioned earlier don't work as they should - I had it connected to the direction pin for step motor driver - pins stay low.

pigpio code:

```py
from time import sleep
import pigpio
from math import *

class Read:
    def __init__(self):
        self.direction_pin = 26
        self.step_pin = 27
        self.microstep0_pin = 10
        self.microstep1_pin = 9
        self.microstep2_pin = 11
        self.en_pin = 4
        self.sleep_pin = 14
        self.reset_pin = 15

        self.steps_per_rev = 6400                       # microsteping if enabled
        self.motor_enable, self.motor_disable = 0, 1        # default state of the pin_ena
        self.stepper_speed_mmps = 30                    # mm per sec
        self.step_delay = 10*10e-9                  # specified by stepper driver in usec
        self.UP, self.DOWN = 1, 0
        self.pos = 0
        self.direction = self.UP
        self.target_pos, self.target_pos_mm = 0, 0
        self.mm_per_rv = 40*pi                      # wheel length
        self.step_per_mm = self.steps_per_rev/self.mm_per_rv
        self.max_speed_mmps = 1000/self.step_per_mm     # 111 mm per sec for current setup

        self.pi = pigpio.pi()

        self.pi.write(self.direction_pin, self.direction)
        self.pi.set_mode(self.en_pin, pigpio.OUTPUT)
        self.pi.set_mode(self.direction_pin, pigpio.OUTPUT)
        self.pi.set_mode(self.step_pin, pigpio.OUTPUT)
        self.pi.set_mode(self.microstep0_pin, pigpio.OUTPUT)
        self.pi.set_mode(self.microstep1_pin, pigpio.OUTPUT)
        self.pi.set_mode(self.microstep2_pin, pigpio.OUTPUT)
        self.pi.set_mode(self.sleep_pin, pigpio.OUTPUT)
        self.pi.set_mode(self.reset_pin, pigpio.OUTPUT)
        self.pi.write(self.en_pin, self.motor_disable)
        self.pi.write(self.microstep0_pin, 1)
        self.pi.write(self.microstep1_pin, 1)
        self.pi.write(self.microstep2_pin, 1)
        self.pi.write(self.sleep_pin, 1)
        self.pi.write(self.reset_pin, 1)
        

        self.eject_distance = 126.4  # mm
        self.distance_to_measure = 38.1+49.6+1  # mm
        self.one_step_1_32_mm = 125.9/6400
        self.distance_between_fields = 7.75  # mm
        self.steps_eject = int(self.eject_distance/self.one_step_1_32_mm)
        self.steps_init = int(self.distance_to_measure/self.one_step_1_32_mm)
        self.steps_to_go = int(
            self.distance_between_fields/self.one_step_1_32_mm)
        self.distance_back = self.distance_between_fields*10+self.distance_to_measure
        self.steps_back = self.steps_to_go*10+self.steps_init
        self.eject_flag = False

    def constrain(self, val, min_v, max_v):
        if val < min_v:
            val = min_v
        elif val > max_v:
            val = max_v
        else:
            pass
        return val

    def step(self):
        self.pi.write(self.step_pin, 1)
        sleep(self.step_delay)
        self.pi.write(self.step_pin, 0)

    def move_relative(self, stepper_speed_mmps, target_pos_mm):
        # global pos, direction, target_pos
        dr = -1 if target_pos_mm < 0 else 1
        delta_pos = ceil(abs(target_pos_mm)*self.step_per_mm)*dr
        self.target_pos = self.pos + delta_pos
        # stepper_speed_mmps = round(
        #     self.constrain(stepper_speed_mmps, 1, self.max_speed_mmps-1))
        stepper_speed = stepper_speed_mmps*self.step_per_mm
        pulse_delay = (1/stepper_speed) - self.step_delay

        # checking direction
        previous_direction = self.direction
        self.direction = self.UP if (self.target_pos > self.pos) else self.DOWN
        if (self.direction != previous_direction):
            self.pi.write(self.direction_pin, self.direction)
            sleep(self.step_delay)
            print("Direction changed")
        else:
            pass

        print("Initializing movement from pos: {}, to pos: {}".format(
            self.pos, self.target_pos))

        self.pi.write(self.en_pin, self.motor_enable)

        while self.pos != self.target_pos:
            self.step()
            sleep(pulse_delay)
            self.pos = (self.pos+1) if self.direction else (self.pos-1)

        print("arrived at position: ", self.pos)
        self.pi.write(self.en_pin, self.motor_disable)



    def test_motor(self):
        self.move_relative(self.stepper_speed_mmps,
                           self.eject_distance)
        self.move_relative(self.stepper_speed_mmps,
                           -self.eject_distance)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    aaa = Read()
    aaa.test_motor()
```

This correctly prints "Direction changed" when it was changed - but the motor direction doesn't actually change - pin stays low.

Problem doesn't exist when I use RPi.GPIO lib with the RpiMotorLib:

```py
self.motor = RpiMotorLib.A4988Nema(self.direction_pin, self.step_pin, (
            self.microstep0_pin, self.microstep1_pin, self.microstep2_pin), "DRV8825")
self.motor.motor_go(True, "1/32", 6400, .0005, False, .05)
                sleep(0.1)
self.motor.motor_go(False, "1/32", 6400, .0005, False, .05)
```

I included parts of the code, direction pin is the same in both examples.

Update: This makes completely no sense to me, but when I open python3 from terminal, and try to write to this pin - it works fine. But in my code suddenly it doesn't.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the pigpio code which does not work and the RPi.GPIO code which works.

Comment: @joan Just edited - hope that's enough

Comment: Thanks.  Need more context though.  Need to see how everything is initialised.  Can you share the complete code?

Comment: @joan sure, just did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pigpio does not assign a level to  a GPIO when you open it for output.  It is left at the last level.

I expect  this  is  what causes the behaviour you are seeing.

You need to initialise  the level.

e.g.

```
self.pi.write(self.direction_pin, self.direction)
self.pi.set_mode(self.direction_pin, pigpio.OUTPUT)
```

Comment: I don't understand. Mode on this pin is set when initializing class instance. Then I change state. I don't exactly care whats the state of the pin on the start, because i change it every time I use method move_relative - the problem is that the line `self.pi.write(self.direction_pin, self.direction)` in method move_relative doesn't change the state on the pin

Comment: The direction  pin is an OUPUT pin.  You need  to set the direction pin level to 0  or 1.  At  the moment you leave the pin at the level it was before the program starts.

Comment: This  only needs  to be done in  the  initialisation section when you  do all  the mode settings.  You do actually give  levels to most of the pins  already.